# Event not showing in attendee's calendar

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am using Microsft Graph to add a Calendar Event with an online meeting and I am getting a successful response.

The Event is not however showing in the attendee's calendar. Also, it is failing to send an email to the attendee. I can see the emails bouncing in the event organizer's mailbox.

URL:

```
/v1.0/users/admin@deovratj1990.onmicrosoft.com/events
```

Headers:

```
Authorization: Bearer [ACCESS_TOKEN]
```

Payload:

```json
{
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2021-03-02T16:30:00",
    "timeZone": "India Standard Time"
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2021-03-02T17:00:00",
    "timeZone": "India Standard Time"
  },
  "subject": "Interview scheduled with Deovrat Candidate on Tue, March 02, 4:30 PM - 5:00 PM IST",
  "body": {
    "contentType": "HTML",
    "content": "<body style=\"margin:0px; font-family:Arial\">\nHello,<br/><br/>\n\n\t    Your are scheduled to interview Deovrat Candidate for Java Developer - Deovrat Recruiter.<br/>\n        \n                <br/>View Deovrat Candidate's profile and give your feedback. <br/>\n\t\t\t<a href=\"https://east2.ripplehire.com/ripplehire/interviewer#list/token/73rHnVJ57kPO5YvJEn6V\" target=\"_blank\">https://east2.ripplehire.com/ripplehire/interviewer#list/token/73rHnVJ57kPO5YvJEn6V</a><br/>\n    \n\t<p>When: Tuesday, 02 Mar 2021</p>\n\t<p>Type: Video Interview</p>\n\t\n<hr style=\"border: 1px dashed black;\" />\n\n\t<table style=\"width:100%\" >\n\t   <thead>\n\t\t   <tr>\n\t\t\t   <th align=\"left\"><span style=\"font-weight: bold\">Time</span></th>\n\t\t\t   <th align=\"left\"><span style=\"font-weight: bold\">Interviewer</span></th>\n\t\t\t   \n\t\t   </tr>\n\t   </thead>\n\t   <tbody>\n\n\t\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t   <td align=\"left\"> 4:30 PM - 5:00 PM IST</td>\n\t\t\t   <td align=\"left\">interviewer1@deovratj1990.onmicrosoft.com</td>\n\t\t\t   \n\t\t   </tr>\n\t\t</tbody>\n\t</table>\n\n\t\n\n\t<p>Candidate contact Info</p>\n\t<hr style=\"border: 1px dashed black;\" />\n\t<p>Deovrat Candidate, jalgaonkar.deovrat@gmail.com</p>\n \t<br/><br/>\n   <span style=\"text-decoration: none\"> Regards,<br/>\n   \t<span>Deovrat Recruiter</span><br/>\n\t     \t\t<span>admin@deovratj1990.onmicrosoft.com</span><br/>\n\t</body>"
  },
  "attendees": [
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "address": "interviewer1@deovratj1990.onmicrosoft.com"
      },
      "type": "required"
    }
  ],
  "isOnlineMeeting": true,
  "onlineMeetingProvider": "teamsForBusiness"
}
```

Comment: What type of tenant do you have and would you share the email error?

Comment: I am getting following error for email address interviewer1@deovratj1990.onmicrosoft.com:
Your message wasn't delivered because the recipient's email provider rejected it.

Comment: Does `interviewer1@deovratj1990.onmicrosoft.com` have a mailbox in the tenant? Is that user able to open up their mailbox in [Outlook web](https://outlook.office365.com/owa)?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur yes. I can login to office365 and then can go to outlook web.

Comment: This sounds like an Exchange configuration issue. Are you able to send email to interviewer1@deovratj1990.onmicrosoft.com directly?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur Yes.

Comment: Long shot, have you tried adding the `Mail.Send` permission scope? I understand the docs don't mention this, thus the "long shot". :)

Comment: Yuhu. Now it is working. Thank you very much.